# Accessing the NVMe flash drive of the April 2016 MacBook 12" (A1534)

Tags: ubuntu, arch-linux, system-installation, dual-boot, macintosh

I'm trying to install Linux on the new April 2016 MacBook 12" (A1534).

**Booting from USB via EFI works fine:** I tried Arch Linux (2016.05.01, kernel 4.5.1) and Ubuntu (16.04, kernel 4.4.0-21; and Lubuntu 15.10). I had to pass the kernel options `noapic` in the Arch Linux case and `noapic acpi=off noacpi nomodeset` in the Ubuntu case – otherwise the screen stays blank and the kernel doesn't boot.

**Even the wireless card works out-of-the-box** (Broadcom BCM4350 802.11ac 14e4:43a3). Also suspend-to-RAM works. (Keyboard and touchpad don't work, but these are not my priority at the moment.)

**However, the kernel doesn't detect the built-in flash drive** (the MacBook doesn't have a further storage medium). That is, `blkid` and `cat /proc/partitions` do not show any entries pertaining to the flash drive. Based on suggestions for older MacBooks, I loaded the kernel module `nvme`, and, since the flash drive reports an incorrect PCI device class, manually bound it with:

```
echo 106b 2003 > /sys/bus/pci/drivers/nvme/new_id
```

The dmesg output is non-informative, it just reports that the probe failed. The flash drive reports under `lspci -nn` as:

```
01:00.0 Mass storage controller [0180]: Apple Inc. Device [106b:2003] (rev 11)
```

Note that this is different from previous versions of the MacBook (where the PCI ID was 106b:2001). The flash drive is detected from the Grub shell and works just fine from Mac OS X.

What should I try next? I'm hoping that there are indeed further suggestions, at this point I'm at a loss.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can now happily confirm that **accessing the built-in flash drive works without problems** using kernel 4.6.0-rc7 and manually binding the device using:

```
echo 106b 2003 > /sys/bus/pci/drivers/nvme/new_id
```

I'll submit a patch which will make the manual binding superfluous.

During testing I had one episode of spurious timeouts which I was never able to reproduce again. The driver seems to be stable even when doing moderately disk-intensive stuff.

The only remaining problems with the MacBook are:

1. Audio playback doesn't work (recordings works fine).
2. Keyboard and touchpad don't work.

Comment: The flash drive also works with the newly-released kernel 4.6. The patch is at http://lists.infradead.org/pipermail/linux-nvme/2016-May/004618.html, but there is probably no need to apply it locally since the workaround by manual binding is so simple.